# Check succeeding records for special constraint

Tags: sql, hsqldb, consistency

A mathematical rule must apply to all records with the same name identifier:

x(n) = x(n-1) + y(n-1) where n are the elements sorted by x.

A special case: if y=0, the following value of x does not need to stick to this rule. As an example:

```
Name    X    Y
   a    0    1
   a    1    2
   a    2    5   <----- this is invalid because 1 + 2 != 2
   b    0    1
   b    1    0
   b    14   3   <----- this is okay because the preceding element had y = 0
   b    16   1   <----- this is invalid because 14 + 3 != 16
```

The task is to filter the invalid elements.

Without the special case of y=0 I came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE EXCEPT
SELECT NAME, X, Y FROM (
SELECT * FROM TABLE JOIN SELECT NAME AS N, X AS XX, Y AS YY
ON NAME = N WHERE X = 0 OR XX+YY = X)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion how to handle Y=0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to your problem. I made an assumption that your table is named 'a'

Here is the code:

```
SELECT name,
       x,
       y
FROM
  (SELECT a1.name,
           a1.x,
           a1.y,

     (SELECT a3.x + a3.y
      FROM a AS a3
      WHERE a3.name=a1.name
        AND a3.y<>0
        AND a3.x =
          (SELECT max(a2.x)
           FROM a AS a2
           WHERE a2.name=a1.name
             AND a2.x<a1.x)) AS s1
   FROM a AS a1)
WHERE s1 IS NULL
  OR x=s1
```

and the result is:

```
a   0   1
a   1   2
b   0   1
b   1   0
b   14  3
```